# Create an alternative ID in query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, masking

I am trying to add a column in a SQL query to use as an alternative ID.
The data has this format:

```
UserID | Value
---------------
1      | 23
2      | 10
1      | 45
```

I'd like to create another column that is another number but respects the ID uniqueness. Like so

```
MaskedID | Value
---------------
9      | 23
8      | 10
9      | 45
```

I've tried using a subquery which creates a table with a random number, but the random number is not staying the same for the first ID:

```
Select b.Masked, a.value
from table a
left join 
(select distinct(UserID), dbms_random.value(1,100000) as Masked) b on a.UserID=b.UserID
```

But that results in:

```
MaskedID | Value
---------------
7      | 23
8      | 10
9      | 45
```

The # of userIDs may change with time so it's not something that should be predefined. Would a CTE keep the random numbers from being regenerated in the final table?

Comment: There are lots of options. But what's the purpose of this new column?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. It acts on an entire row.

Comment: @MT0 We had this in my job. People kept doing it. So I wrote an email::: "... I had a good laugh. The thing is about SQL, you can have as many parenthesis as you wish. So if I do 
`SELECT DISTINCT(UG.USERID), (UG.USERDESC),(UG.EMAIL), (UG.ACL) FROM USERS UG` 
It will be just as good. Parenthesis act as separator in SQL and therefore 
 `SELECT DISTINCT(UG.USERID),` Is same as `SELECT DISTINCT UG.USERID,`" ... SO!!! Potentially OP just separated `DISTINCT` and `USERID` using parenthesis vs space. So, who is getting caught here, OP or you? This is a contest

Comment: @MT0 it runs just fine for me boss

Comment: @PaulW I need the information that a specific user may have many rows, but I do not want to be able to trace the userID

Comment: @Rickerz, then you want something that can't be reverse engineered back to the original value. A hash value (`dbms_crypto.hash`, `ORA_HASH`, `STANDARD_HASH`) are all good options. They will always return the same value for the same input, but you can't reverse engineer the original value. I'll put this in an answer so you can see an example.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks, I've tried after T.S.'s suggestion and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a hash function. It will alway return the same value for the same input, but can't be reverse engineered to the original value. The oldest and simplest is `ORA_HASH`:

```
select ORA_HASH(USERID) Masked, a.value
from table a
```

This produces a number, but with enough values you could get a collision. Even better is the newer `STANDARD_HASH` function which is far less likely to give a collision, but which produces an alphanumeric (hexadecimal) output:

```
select STANDARD_HASH(USERID) Masked, a.value
from table a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a GUID for the first of each `UserId` and then use analytic functions to use the same value for all the other rows with the same `UserId`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(maskedid) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) AS maskedid,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ROWNUM)
         WHEN 1
         THEN SYS_GUID()
         END AS maskedid,
         userid,
         value
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (UserID, Value) AS
SELECT 1, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 45 FROM DUAL;
```

May output:

| MASKEDID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 0x0BFDC951F97909BCE06502163E386F05 | 23 |
| 0x0BFDC951F97909BCE06502163E386F05 | 45 |
| 0x0BFDC951F97A09BCE06502163E386F05 | 10 |

---

You could use any function rather than `SYS_GUID()` such as `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(maskedid) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) AS maskedid,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY ROWNUM)
         WHEN 1
         THEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 1e6)
         END AS maskedid,
         userid,
         value
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which may randomly output:

| MASKEDID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 84046.38920350070167103410156941056149 | 23 |
| 84046.38920350070167103410156941056149 | 45 |
| 297835.63547525613908362909300172303338 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zRQjf51b)

Answer (score 0):

This will have a unique Id for you every time.

```
select col1, col2, SYS_GUID() uniqueId from table1
```

I believe that you can also use oracle row ID, it is unique

```
select col1, col2, ROWID uniqueId from table1
```

Oracle also has row number but it will change with the row sort

```
select col1, col2, ROWNUM uniqueId from table1
```

But I believe, what you REALLY need here is to take 2 columns that make "something"+value unique, and hash it - `select ORA_HASH(col1 || col2)`

Comment: This will create unique IDs for every row (like my last example) no?

Comment: @Rickerz will your new ID need to be persistent for each row? or it can change every time? Do you need to map a particular row to the same unique id?

Comment: It can change every time, i only need to be able to 'hide' the original ID, but keeping the information that a user has said values. So yes mapping. My solution's problem was that the randomized part was somehow being randomized even for the same ID, where I thought using the subquery would go around that

Comment: @Rickerz I believe, what you REALLY need here is to take 2 columns that make "something"+value unique, and hash it - `select ORA_HASH(col1 || col2)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply take one (static)random number and do some math on it to get unique persitent id as follows:

```
Select 987654321 - a.USER_ID AS MaskedID, a.value
from table a;
```

You can also use some complex math with multiplication or division(with caution, try to avoid division) also to create the `MaskedID`.

Comment: It may or may not be a text field. Forgot to mention